# how do i position a p-growl element on the bottom right of the screen?

Tags: css, angular, angular5, primeng

I want the growl message to be fixed to the bottom right and i've been trying to do so by overriding the css classes of p-growl. My first attempt was to override the `.ui-growl` class like so:

```
::ng-deep .ui-growl {   
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

(The border is just for testing.)
This has the effect that the growcontainer itself will elongate itself from the top all the way to the bottom where it sticks to the bottom right. The actual message growl inside the message growl container still appears at the top of the container. My second attempt was to apply the css rules to the css class of the message element itself `.ui-growl-item` .

This does make the actual growl stick to the bottom right but it also has the unfortunate effect of seemingly erasing all the other css style rules within the default `.ui-growl-item`, turning the growl from green/red to practically invisible.

[image]

I indicated the growl after the css class override with the pink arrow. All you can see are some white letters and part of the error cross symbol. The green block is not part of the growl but part of the background.

Does anyone have an idea on how i could implement the desired css rules on the growl while maintaining the other css rules that i don't want to change? I think i've found the default file here https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2686100/ but i wouldn't know what default css rules i should include in order to prevent it from losing its color. What complicates things is that the color is conditional, it turns red when its an error, green for success etc.

EDIT:

I've tried using `top` and `left` instead to achieve the same thing but it isn't a viable option because when the message content is large part of it may disappear out of the viewport. On the other hand will small messages not stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, Just change the `top` attribute of the `.ui-growl` class.

By default, the class looks like.

```
.ui-growl {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Change it to. Or add a new style.

```
.ui-growl {
    top: 80vh !important;
}
```

Adjust the top, to suit your position. The `vh` here is ViewPort Height, considered in percentages of the total viewport.

UPDATE: Use this style Override

```
.ui-growl {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: this only works when the growl is Always of a fixed height. The length of the message that is displayed within the growl also determines the height of the growlbox. So when i place the growl at the bottom, using your approach, and the message is very long, part of it will protrude outside the viewport.

Comment: Yes, man. I missed it. Updated the answer with the new CSS. Hope this works for you. @Maurice